In golang: How do I chain functions and return a different object pointer?
Each element (structure/class) shares an internal class called "element". What happens is that each function of each of the elements (div, p, span, button...) must return itself in order to continue chaining the functions of the current element.
It happens that each element, in addition to containing global attributes (functions), has its own.
The only solution I found is a crude one: write the same functions in each of the elements with the only difference that the element to return is a pointer to itself (*div, *p, *span, *button...etc).
I would like to be able to write structures (html elements) that compose different attributes and that return the pointer to themselves in order to do the magic of chaining functions.
Example: The html structure will have a method called Lang(value string) which will complete the array of attributes with lang="en" and only this element has this attribute.
I would like to be able to write cleaner, smarter code. I've tried generics, but I'm not getting anywhere.
If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it.
Here's some code:
func newElement(tagName string, hasClosingTag bool) *element {
    return &element{tagName: tagName, hasClosingTag: hasClosingTag}
}

type element struct {
    tagName       string
    hasClosingTag bool
    attributes    []string
    classes       []string
    styles        []string
    elements      []fmt.Stringer

    htmx *htmx
}

// String retorna texto HTML del elemento actual, para ser renderizado.
func (p *element) String() string {
    if p.htmx != nil {
        p.addAttributes(p.htmx.getAttributes())
        p.addClasses(p.htmx.getClasses())
    }
    if p.hasClosingTag {
        return fmt.Sprintf("<%[1]v%v%v%v>%v</%[1]v>", p.tagName, p.getAttributes(), p.getClasses(), p.getStyles(), p.getElements())
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("<%v%v%v%v />", p.tagName, p.getAttributes(), p.getClasses(), p.getStyles())
}

func (p *element) addAttribute(attr string, value ...any) {
    attr = strings.TrimSpace(attr)
    if attr == "" {
        return
    }
    if value == nil {
        p.attributes = append(p.attributes, attr)
    } else {
        p.attributes = append(p.attributes, fmt.Sprintf(`%v="%v"`, attr, value[0]))
    }
}

func (p *element) addAttributes(attr ...string) {
    for _, s := range attr {
        s = strings.TrimSpace(s)
        if s != "" {
            p.attributes = append(p.attributes, s)
        }
    }
}

func (p *element) addClasses(class ...string) {
    for _, c := range class {
        c = strings.TrimSpace(c)
        if c != "" {
            p.classes = append(p.classes, c)
        }
    }
}

func (p *element) addStyles(style ...string) {
    for _, s := range style {
        s = strings.TrimSpace(s)
        if s != "" && s[len(s)-1] != ';' {
            s += ";"
        }
        if s != "" {
            p.styles = append(p.styles, s)
        }
    }
}

func (p *element) addElements(el ...fmt.Stringer) {
    p.elements = append(p.elements, el...)
}

func (p *element) getAttributes() string {
    if len(p.attributes) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(` %v`, strings.Join(p.attributes, " "))
}
func (p *element) getClasses() string {
    if len(p.classes) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(` class="%v"`, strings.Join(p.classes, " "))
}
func (p *element) getStyles() string {
    if len(p.styles) == 0 {
        return ""
    }
    return fmt.Sprintf(` style="%v"`, strings.Join(p.styles, " "))
}
func (p *element) getElements() string {
    var s string
    for _, el := range p.elements {
        s += el.String()
    }

    return s
}




// example
Body(
    Div().Id("div-one").Class(`class-one class-two`).Hidden().Content(
        Div().Id("div-two").Style(`background-color: #c3c3c3;`),
        Div().Id("div-three").Class("class-three-1"),
        Div(
            Div().Id("div-other").Content(
                InnerHtml("This is a normal text"),
            ),
        ),
    ),
)


This can be done using a few structs instead of functions, and it would be easier to write and read. But if you insist on doing this, first start by defining your API consistently. Looking at div, I'd expect body to have content as opposed to getting content as an argument. It can be done with a struct element containing a tagName and attributes. Each function returns the element pointer itself. Content  method gets arguments where each arg becomes a child of the element.

I don't understand you, could you please give me an example of the  element and that it has a  element inside?

In my opinion, this type of construct does not improve the readability or maintainability of the end product. The following is a much more Go idiomatic way of constructing this (this is only a sketch of the idea. You can find third party DOM libraries. Some of these are better at handling HTML.)
type Text struct {
   Parent Node
   Content string
}

type Element struct {
   Parent Node
   Tag string
   Attr map[string]string
   Children []Node
}

type Node interface {
   // Methods shared by Element and Text
   GetChildren() []Node
}

Then:
body:=&Element {  Tag: "body" }
div1:=&Element{
         Parent: body,
         Tag: "div",
         Attr: map[string]string { "id": "div1", etc. }
      }
body.Children=[]Node {div1}
text1:=&Text{Parent:div1,Content:"inner HTML content"}
div1.Children=[]Node{text1}

That said, you can achieve the functional way of doing it by defining some additional methods and functions. For instance:
func Elem(tag) *Element {
   return &Element{Tag:tag,Attr:make(map[string]string)}
}

func (e *Element) Id(id string) *Element{ 
   e.Attr["id"]=id
   return e
}

func (e *Element) Attribute(key,value string) *Element {
   e.Attr[key]=value
   return e
}

func (e *Element) TextChild() *Text {
   t:=&Text{Parent:e}
   e.Children=append(e.Children,t)
   return t
}

func (e *Element) ElementChild(tag string) *Element {
   child:=&Element{Parent: e, Tag:tag}
   e.Children=append(e.Children,child)
   return child
}

func (e *Element) End() *Element {return e.Parent}

func (t *Text) Content(s string) *Text{
   t.Content=s
   return t
}

func (t *Text) End() *Text() {return t.Parent}

So you can write:
Elem("body").
   ElementChild("div").Id("div1").
      TextChild().Content("text").End().
   ElementChild("div2").Id("div2").End() ..etc

Again, this is only a sketch, and as you go deeper into implementing this, you will end up with a partial DOM implementation anyway.
